# iOS : Connected to wifi but no internet access

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have enable my mobile data (3G/4G) but there is no data left in my Mobile Network.

Is it possible to know above condition in swift.

I have checked below code but its giving me wrong information. Below condition is only satisfied  when off the mobile data. My requirement is mobile data is ON and no internet avialable

```
    let reachability = Reachability(hostName: "https://www.google.com")
    if reachability.currentReachabilityStatus() == NotReachable {

    }
```

Comment: This is a known issue(?). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260833/ios-reachabilitywithhostname-yes-although-it-should-be-no) and [here](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/115)

Comment: Are you telling its not possible

Comment: Yes, it is not possible with the current implementation of Reachability. Initializing with hostName just confirms whether it is a valid host name or not but does not check for network connectivity on runtime.

Comment: Is there any other  third party, which can resolve this issue

Comment: Why don't you hit the URL and if you dont get any response, it can be said that there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: IS IT GOOD SOLUTION.....

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Thanks Puneet for your valuable update

Answer (score 2):

Find the solution which worked for me

```
func isConnectedToNetwork()->Bool {
    var Status:Bool = false
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    _ = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response) as NSData?
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            Status = true
        }
    }
    return Status
}
```